# How to prove the discontinuity and differentiability of a distance function?

Tags: functions, derivatives, continuity

Let $I=\{1\}\cup \{2\}\subset\mathbb{R}$. For $x\in\mathbb{R}$, let $f(x)=\text{dist}(x,I)=\inf{|x-y|:y\in I}$ then
check the continuity and differentiability of $f$ on $\mathbb{R}$. 
First I have found out the functions by taking the value of $x$ in the open intervals $(-\infty, 1)$, $(2,\infty)$, $(1,3/2)$ and $(3/2,2)$ which are $1-x$, $x-2$,$x-1$ and $2-x$ respectively. But I could not get how to proceed further. I tried to do it graphically but I could not do it. Please help me with it.

Comment: Your distance function is a function $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. If you draw the graph of this function, you might get a better intuition of whether it is continuous and/or differentiable

Comment: I tried actually but I could not solve it graphically.

Comment: Where you able to draw the graph?

Comment: I drew it in my notebook..I don't know how to draw a graph here..(thought that it will be complicated to draw a graph here so)